# CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'. Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Create failed for Database 'myDB'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=14.0.17119.0+((SSMS_Rel).170517-0412)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Create+Database&LinkId=20476

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

---

CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 262)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=12.00.2269&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=262&LinkId=20476

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

I don't have an admin account outside of 'sa'(ı dont know the password). This account deauthorize(ı can't authorize). What can I do?

Comment: What can you do? Ask someone that does have higher permissions to elevate your permissions so that you can `CREATE` a database. If they say no, then you won't be able to; you'll need to get someone who can to do it for you (very common in business environments). You can't "get around" permissions in SQL Server, if you could they would be utterly pointless.

Comment: you can also hack the SA password by sniffing network packets using tools such as FERN in a Kali Linux distro, but i would go for Larnu's solution :D

Comment: I know these. I've encountered such a problem on a personal computer. No account is authorized. I will try to setup again. Thank you.
i will look at kali linux :)

Comment: My comment was a joke my friend, if your environment is a personal computer you should have SA password (it is required when you install SQL Server) or at least a Windows account which has sysadmin privileges.

Comment: So, is this a local installation and you have *lost* the `sa` password?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/2c3XxmA.png
an old personal computer

Answer (score 0):

PREREQUISITES:

1. **Administrative privileges needed** on Host Server.
2. **Downtime of approximately 10 minutes** needed because SQL Server would be started in ‘Single User’ mode.

PROCEDURE:

1. RDP to the server with the account which has ‘Admin’ rights on the Hosting Windows box. Using a service account is good idea. -> s*kip this if your server is a local machine*
2. Open ‘SQL Server Configuration Manager’ :

Start>All Programs>Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (or 2005)>Configuration Tools>SQL Server Configuration
Manager

3. Start SQL Services in ‘Single User Mode:

Right Click on SQL Services and click ‘properties’
Go ‘Advanced’ tab then open ‘Start up Parameters’
Write ‘-m’ at the end, then click ‘OK’.
This would open a dialog box informing that SQL Services need to be restarted for this. Click ‘OK’.

Stop dependent services like SQL Agent. Restart SQL Services.

4. Connect to SQL instance using SQLCMD

Right Click on Command prompt, select ‘Run as Administrator’ (in Windows 2003 and lower, run as administrator is not available and not required)
Now connect to SQL instance using SQLCMD, write below command:
`SQLCMD –E –S <instance name>`

5. Now create a windows login (i.e. group account used by DB team), use below command:

`CREATE LOGIN [Login_name] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
 GO`

6. Now grant ‘sysadmin’ access to this newly created login, use below command:

`EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = 'login_name', @rolename = 'sysadmin'
 GO`

7. Restart SQL Services in multi user mode. For doing that, remove ‘-m’ from Startup parameters and restart SQL
   Services.

Answer (score 0):

You need administrative privileges.

When opening SQL right click on it and click "Run as Administrator"